# Earliest task to add an unmanaged jar dependency so that it's available to compile

Tags: scala, sbt

What step in SBT should I add a task dependency if I want to copy jars to the `lib` (`unmanagedBase`) before compilation?

If I simply have `compile in Compile` depend on this `copyLibs` task,

```
compile in Compile := {
  copyLibs.value
  (compile in Compile).value
}
```

then it’ll only work if I run `compile` twice which make me think I’m copying the jars too late.
I've found the same issue when adding to `unmanagedJars` and `unmanagedClasspath`.

What's the earliest task in the `compile` task graph I can add this to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure attaching it directly to compile is the best way to do it, but it should work if you make `compile` *depend* on your task:

```
compile in Compile := (compile in Compile).dependsOn(copyLibs).value
```

You can read more about [Task graph](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Task-Graph.html) in the sbt documentation to understand better task dependencies and the way they are executed and cached.

Comment: Forgive the -1! Accepted as answer but can't seem to undo the errant downvote.

Comment: Nope. "...Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited." Try trivially editing it?

Comment: Done! -1 removed